# Possible environments to generate wide range of graphics objects on-the-fly

Tags: graphics, on-the-fly

I am developing an online assessment package for elementary grade math (K-6) Many questions will need to contain graphics such as shown on this image:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwsi91l3bp9t3de/samplegraphics.PNG

All graphics needs to be generated on-the-fly (apart from photos of real objects that are stored in a database) - so that unlimited number of problems can be created). Another requirement is that this works well on both desktop and mobile devices.

I am looking for an advice as to what language / graphics package would be best suited for this purpose. I would rather do everything in one environment. If some of the above can not be generated on the fly, I would consider (but not prefer) off-line generation of many examples that are then stored in a database. 
I have considered the following

php+gd -- seems nice for manipulating images; however 3D not readily available.

jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php seems like a nice addition for spiffy graphs

There also seems to be a 3D rendered for php phpclasses.org/package/3364-PHP-Compose-and-render-3D-object-models.html -- my 3D requirements are modest (basic shapes, no animation)

---

JS with different plugins i.e. threejs.org/  for 3D - but this seems like an overkill for my needs

there is also js interface to html 5 canvas : calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/

and this: keith-wood.name/svgRef.html

---

Google charts also seems very simple to use, but it doesn't provide everything I need

---

CSS3 - seems like it can do everything (??)

---

gnuplot (??) - not on-the-fly

---

Basically, I am looking for the easiest way to accomplish this, without reinventing the wheel - I am just not quite sure what the trade-offs of different approaches are.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place to get suggestions of what tool to use. It's best for solving a specific problem with something you're already working on. You might have better luck on one of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I did look at other Stack Exchange sites, and have not found an appropriate one - this one seemed "the least inappropriate". Sorry for the bother.